# DocuSign HTML headers and footers

Tags: docusignapi

If I'm using an anchor for signer initials, and I want it to appear on every single page.  Can I do this with DocuSign using an HTML document?

It's easier for us to create and maintain HTML templates to add to envelopes than it is Word docs or PDFs.  However none of the methods of trying to get an HTML repeating footer (the footer prints on every page) seem to work.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign will accept a wide variety of document types, but upon import into the DocuSign system, all documents are converted to PDF format.  So, while it's feasible to supply an HTML file to DocuSign, don't expect DocuSign to interpret/process any of the HTML code that your HTML file contains, because as soon as it's imported into DocuSign it's no longer an HTML file -- it's just plain text.

So, if you want to use anchor text for placement of signer initials at the bottom of each page, then the document you upload to DocuSign (regardless of file format) will need to explicitly contain that anchor text string at the bottom of each page.

Comment: How does DocuSign convert HTML into PDF?  The mechanism used might help me position things properly.

Comment: I don't know the details of the conversion process -- just that all files (regardless of original format) end up being just plain-text (PDF) in the DocuSign system.  Regarding determining whether placement of your anchor text results in desired placement of DocuSign tabs, trial and error is likely your best bet.

Comment: It is converted through **Rasterization** - which is a rendering process for taking an image (in this case what the HTML would show) and converting it into pixels.  This is how the DocuSign service is able to accept such a wide range of input documents...